# Adding A New Line Every Three Digits

Tags: java, netbeans

Okay, I am trying to add a new line every three letters. The goal is to have 20 rows of randomized capital letters. With 3 capital letters per row.

I randomized the numbers and then converted them to a string. Then outputted the string. I have 60 random capital letters in one straight String, but I can't figure out how to add new lines, since each letter is randomized I can't tell java what to search for like I did before. I have tried using an if statement and add an "/n" at the end, but it just got messy and difficult. And the operator commands I couldn't figure out how to apply every three letters either.

Here is the code I have so far under the "wrightRandomCodesToFile"

```
package mp05;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static final int PRODUCT_COUNT = 20;
    private static final int CHARACTERS_PER_CODE = 3;
    private static int charA;
    private static int preChars;
    private static String preLetters;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* (1) Generate three character alphabetic prefix codes. */
        writeRandomCodesToFile("prefix.txt", 'A', 'Z',
                              CHARACTERS_PER_CODE, PRODUCT_COUNT);
        // when you hit run, there is 3 numbers. six digits though.

        /* (2) Generate three character alphabetic suffix codes. */
        writeRandomCodesToFile("suffix.txt", 'A', 'Z',
                               CHARACTERS_PER_CODE, PRODUCT_COUNT);

        /* (3) Generate three character numeric inline codes. */
        writeRandomCodesToFile("inline.txt", '0', '9',
                               CHARACTERS_PER_CODE,  PRODUCT_COUNT);

        /* (4) Merge the two alphabetic and one numeric code to produce the
         * final product code. */
        mergeProductCodesToFile("prefix.txt", "inline.txt", "suffix.txt",
                                "productCode.txt");
    }// end main()


    /* (1),(2),(3) Generate the alphanumeric codes. These are three aphanumeric
     * character combinations generated randomly with each character in the
     * range A-Z | 0-9. Thus you will have codes from AAA-ZZZ | 000-999.
     *
     * Write numberOfCodesToGenerate codes to the specified file.
     */
    public static void writeRandomCodesToFile(String codeFile,
                                              char fromChar, char toChar,
                                              int numberOfCharactersPerCode,
                                              int numberOfCodesToGenerate) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        charA = 65;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            try (
                PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new File("prefix.txt")); //Creates File
            ) {
                preChars = charA + rnd.nextInt(26);
                preLetters = String.valueOf((char) preChars);
                System.out.print(preLetters);    

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }// end writeRandomCodesToFile()

    /* (4) Merge the two alphabetic and one numeric code to produce the final
     * product code. The final product code will consist of <prefix><inline><suffix>.
     * Each code will be in the range AAA000AAA-ZZZ999ZZZ.
     *
     * Merge by using a prefix, an inline and a suffix code from their corresponding
     * files. Each individual code (pre, in, post) is used exactly once, and all values are used.
     *
     * Write these final product codes to the file specified in productFile.
     */
    public static void mergeProductCodesToFile(String prefixFile,
                                               String inlineFile,
                                               String suffixFile,
                                               String productFile) {


    }// end mergeProductCodesToFile()
}// end Main
```

Comment: Please put the code in the actual question rather than using an external website.

Comment: Can output be mixed alpha-numeric, eg "A2B", or must they be all letters *or* all numbers?

Comment: They must be all capital letters. I randomize numbers, then convert the numbers to the corresponding letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring your context and answering the question as per the title:

Given a long string, to insert a newline every 3 chars:

```
str = str.replaceAll("...", "$0\n");
```

Comment: your regex always impress me . Great answer.

Comment: I tried what you said, but it didn't seem to work. This is what I did:  

       `preChars = charA + rnd.nextInt(26);  
        preLetters = String.valueOf((char)(preChars));  
        str = preLetters.replaceAll("...", "$0\n");  
        System.out.print(str);`  

And the output came out to be the same.

Comment: @SpencerBochantin Works here `public static void main(String...args) {
  String str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  
  str = str.replaceAll("...", "$0\n");
  System.out.println(str);
 }`

Comment: But how do I get it to work with randomized letters? I messed around with the code you gave and if I replace the "..." with "A", the program does add a "\n" after every "A". But "..." Doesn't seem to be working. I still get one straight line.  EDIT: I also noticed if I just put only one "." It seems to add a new line every letter. But as soon as I add another dot it doesn't work.

Comment: @SpencerBochantin the `...` is not an ellipsis (a placeholder), it's literally the code (ie three dots). If `str = "abcdefgh"` *before* the call, it will be `"abc\ndef\ngh"` *afterwards*.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking each dot meant a letter over. Only problem is that since the letters are random, I can't set an assortment of letters to split.

Comment: @spencer I think you are still missing the point. If you create your output as one long string, this code (exactly as-is, ie with the dots) will split it every 3 chars with a newline. And can you answer my question above: is `A2B` a valid code, or must the codes be *either* all letters *or* all numbers?

Comment: It has to be all capital letters.

Comment: I tried implementing what you said to do again. But I am still just getting one long String from the output.

Comment: @spencer yes - the long string contains newlines; just write the whole string to the file. You'll get separate lines in the file.

Comment: I am still confused. Why would the text written on the file be different than what is outputted? Also, I use fout.print(preLetters) and I just get nothing instead.

Comment: @Spencer I may post a complete answer, but before I do, please clarify the spec: The comments say `...three alphanumeric character combinations generated randomly with each character in the range A-Z | 0-9` but then it says `Thus you will have codes from AAA-ZZZ | 000-999`, but this is incorrect - you will get codes in the range `000-ZZZ`, ie if ordered, the codes after `999` would be `A00`, `A01` etc. If the output was truly meant to be *either* `AAA-ZZZ` *or* `000-999`, the term "alphanumeric" ("both letters and numbers") should not be present. So, is it `AAA-ZZZ | 000-999` *or* `000-ZZZ`?

Comment: I finally figured it out. I ended up doing all the solving in a different method. Then each time it ran through it was creating 3 times more than I intended. I guess I just got confused since I was using my instructor's template. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
class test{

    public static String randomString(String chars, int length) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            buf.append(chars.charAt(rand.nextInt(chars.length())));
        }
        return buf.toString().replaceAll("...","$0\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        String myString = randomString("ABCDEFGHIJKLMONQRSTUVWXYZ",60);

        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("fileame.txt");
            pw.println(myString);
            pw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```